# How to place variables into .html

Tags: javascript, jquery

want to create an output of gathered variables from a script. but can't seem to input the variables in HTML markup in the script.

```
$(".regclick3").click(function(){
    $('.regtarget4').trigger('click');
     var data1 = $("[name='f_k_page_title']").val();
     var data2 =  $("[name='f_extended_user_email']").val();

     $(".divoutput").html(data1+ " "   + data2);
});
```

html

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="f_extended_user_email" />
<input type="text" name="f_k_page_title" />
</form>

<div class="capture_data">Capture</div>

<div class="divoutput"></div>
```

Is it possible to add class and variables to the script? Can there be if statements, so if var data1 exists then display "X"

Thank you

Comment: Cannot clearly understand your issue

Comment: provide your hmtl or create a snippet.

Comment: Your string concatenation in your example is wrong.

Comment: Hey Shakti, I am trying to add html to the output. with the varibles. Also is it possible to create if statements? So it only displays a var if it has a value, if not display a message.

Comment: Learn to use a ternary operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: is there a guide on the correct format to add html to this script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment yes you can show HTML only if it exists otherwise something default like so:

```js
function showMe()
{
  var theVal = $('#name').val();
  if(!theVal)
  {
    theVal = "Oop's No value entered";
  }
  $('#theValue').html(theVal);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<br/>
The value is :: <span id="theValue"></span>
<br/>
<button onClick="showMe();">Show Me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks this seems better. Haribol!

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(".divoutput").html(data1+ " "  data2+);
```

//    Yah! its possible what your missed + symbol in your code  use like below https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/xdoWYy

```
   $(".divoutput").html(data1+ " " + data2);
```

Comment: how do i add more to it, divs and classes?

Comment: $(".divoutput").html("<div class='class1'>"+data1+ " " + data2+"</div>"); or var arr=["<div class='class1'>",data1,"",data2,"</div>"];  $(".divoutput").html(arr.join(""));   you can able to add n number tags with class